# Replace span content excluding nested span

Tags: html, replace, nested

I'm trying to replace the text of a nested span

```
<div class="one">
        <span>
             <span class="two">Europe</span> <br>
              ${blah:123:param} {clock}
        </span>
</div>
```

I want to find the text that contains "param" and replace the whole thing "${blah:123:param}" with some text, without messing with the span above or the "{clock}".

I have this but it changes the whole span

```
$('.one > span').html($('#test').val());
```

I'm retrieving the value from #test which is somewhere else.

Comment: Can you place `${blah:123:param}` in its own element? Is there a particular reason why it must be nested directly in that span?

Comment: I wish :) Cannot because I don't control the output :/

Comment: After `${blah:123:param} {clock}` has been rendered, is there any unique patterns between the param and clock? What are some example outputs?

Comment: The output is irrelevant, the change has to happen before they render

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If the content comes from an external source; then, it must be evaluated before used... Unless a callback function is passed instead. Where and how are you getting the content?